# How to add yes/no combo box to the each cells in one column in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, combobox, cells

See title. How can I do this in Excel 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the 2010 interface, in 2003 you'd go to the Validation dialog and add a List check.

In code that'd be:

```
columns(1).validation.add xlValidateList,,,"yes,no"
```

Comment: In excel 2010 it doesn't work I found how to put combobox into one cell but how to put into all cells of one column have not found :(.
For one cell needs to enable Developer Tab in Excel 2010 and insert combobox from this tab.

Comment: You can manually select the first column, go to the `Data` tab, select `Data Validation`, go to `List`, and enter `yes, no` in the box below for the list items. This will work, but I think the OP is asking how to use Form Controls (not sure whether checkboxes or dropdowns).

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2007 under the Data tab, you can find it under Data Validation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way in Excel to generate a load of Form Checkboxes linked to underlying cells. If you copy a single checkbox, it will have all the same properties (including linked cell) meaning you will have to edit it manually each time. In order to add a bunch at once, you have to create a VBA function to do it for you.

Thankfully [people smarter than I](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/09/04/excel-adding-checkboxes-the-easy-way/) have already done that. Here is one such example code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub insertCheckboxes()

  Dim myBox As CheckBox
  Dim myCell As Range

  Dim cellRange As String
  Dim cboxLabel As String
  Dim linkedColumn As String

  cellRange = InputBox(Prompt:="Cell Range", _
    Title:="Cell Range")

  linkedColumn = InputBox(Prompt:="Linked Column", _
    Title:="Linked Column")

  cboxLabel = InputBox(Prompt:="Checkbox Label", _
    Title:="Checkbox Label")

  With ActiveSheet
    For Each myCell In .Range(cellRange).Cells
      With myCell
        Set myBox = .Parent.CheckBoxes.Add(Top:=.Top, _ 
          Width:=.Width, Left:=.Left, Height:=.Height)

        With myBox
          .LinkedCell = linkedColumn & myCell.Row
          .Caption = cboxLabel
          .Name = "checkbox_" & myCell.Address(0, 0)
        End With

        .NumberFormat = ";;;"
      End With

    Next myCell
  End With
End Sub
```

You should copy this in to a VBA module. Hit Alt+F11 to open the VBA editor, select the module of your current workbook, and paste that code in. If there is no module in your current workbook, rightclick the workbook name and use `Insert` -> `New Module` to add one.

Return to your workbook and hit Alt-F8 to run a macro. If you run the `insertCheckboxes` macro, you will get the following dialogue:

[image: Enter Range Here]

Enter the range you want checkboxes in (for instance, A1:A10)

[image: Enter Linked Column Here]

Enter the column you want the checkboxes to be linked to (if you select B, that means column B will show the `TRUE`/`FALSE` result of the checkbox).

[image: Enter the Checkbox Label Here]

Enter the label you want on the checkboxes. If you want just the box, leave it blank.

There are a couple small issues with the VBA (for instance, it sets the cells the checkboxes go in to as `;;;` making them display nothing, probably for cases where you link the checkboxes to the cells they are located in), but a little creative engineering should get you around that.

After you've used the macro, you can delete the module -- the macro just creates the checkboxes, it isn't needed to maintain them.

<sub>Note: The above code was tested and worked in Excel 2010 for me. Your environment may vary</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This will help you. this is a visual tutorial. it uses data validation to form the combo box

http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Drop-Down-Box-in-Excel-2007

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.